# keyboard displays in the place of iframe in sencha touch

Tags: iframe, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I am using **cordova 1.8** and sencha touch 2.2.1.My problem is when I click on a textfield it displays keyboard instead of iframe.

This is my sencha code:

```
onfocus : function(){

Ext.getCmp('toolid').hide();

Ext.getCmp('crperid').hide();

Ext.getCmp('eventcvideoid').hide();

    Ext.getCmp('sqlbacklbl').show();
         //   Ext.getCmp('dattimepanelid').setHtml('<iframe id="dtid" src="http://example.com</iframe>');

      // frame.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 1000); 
      Ext.getCmp('dattimepanelid').show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to hide the keyboard

```
var activeElement = document.activeElement;

activeElement.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly'); // Force keyboard to hide on input field.

activeElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'true'); // Force keyboard to hide on textarea field.

Ext.defer(function() {

activeElement.blur();
        // Remove readonly attribute after keyboard is hidden.

activeElement.removeAttribute('readonly');

activeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');

   if(callback) {

     callback.call(scope);

 }

}, 100);
```